# I need a regex to match the attributes of the following string

Tags: javascript, regex

The string:

```
{title id="fsfdsfsdf" link1="http://google.com" link1_title="Some link"}
```

What attribute values I need:

```
fsfdsfsdf, http://google.com, Some link
```

I would need them probably in capturing groups `()`

Regular expressions are really my weak point, so thanks to anyone suggesting a way to do it, or some further resource that could eventually help me solve this.

Comment: Please share the code you tried.

Comment: ... and some correct data. Is that a string?

Comment: Due to the format of this site, you'd probably be best served working through online RegEx tutorials and reading through [the RegEx documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics) here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(\w+)(?==)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/RJu6Lr/1)

**Edit**

Since it's the attribute values and not keys you want. Then you could do something like:

```
="((?:\\"|[^"])*?)"
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/RJu6Lr/2)

```js
var input = "{title id=\"fsfdsfsdf\" link1=\"http://google.com\" link1_title=\"Some link\"}";

const re = /="((?:\\"|[^"])*?)"/g;

match = re.exec(input);

while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = re.exec(input);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
fsfdsfsdf
http://google.com
Some link
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately, maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, I need the attribute "Values" and not the attribute names themselves. Any idea?

Comment: This was really a good starting point to build my own 100% working regex:
`^\{title id="((?:\\"|[^"])*?)"\slink1="((?:\\"|[^"])*?)"\slink1_title="((?:\\"|[^"])*?)"[\s^\}]$` . I needed to match whole string actually and then have the attr. values